# Reallocate memory for both stack and heap pointer

Tags: c++, heap-memory, stack-memory, memory-reallocation

I developped a blocking queue class as follow

```
class Blocking_queue
{
public:
    Blocking_queue();

    int put(void* elem, size_t elem_size);
    int take(void* event);

    unsigned int get_size();

private:

    typedef struct element
    {
        void* elem;
        size_t elem_size;
        struct element* next;
    }element_t;

    std::mutex m_lock;
    std::condition_variable m_condition;
    unsigned int m_size;
    element_t* m_head;
    element_t* m_tail;

};
```

I want the class to be as generic as possible so I'm using a void pointer which is allocated when the element is added to the queue and freed when removed from it.

```
int Blocking_queue::take(void* event)
{
    element_t* new_head = NULL;
    int ret = 0;

    // Queue empty
    if(nullptr == m_head)
    {
        // Wait for an element to be added to the queue
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> unique_lock(m_lock);
        m_condition.wait(unique_lock);
    }

    if(nullptr == realloc(event, m_head->elem_size))
    {
        ret = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Take element from queue
        memcpy(event, m_head->elem, m_head->elem_size);
        ret = m_head->elem_size;
        new_head = m_head->next;
        free(m_head->elem);
        free(m_head);
        m_head = new_head;
        if(nullptr == m_head)
        {
            m_tail = nullptr;
        }
        m_size -= 1;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If the queue is empty, `take()` function waits on `m_condition` until a new element is added.

A pointer `event` has to be given to copy element's content before freeing it.

To be sure that the given pointer has the right size to copy element's content I reallocate the pointer with its size.

The problem I have with this is that it doesn't allow to pass a function's locale variable because it's allocated on the stack.

So if I do something like this

```
void function()
{
    unsigned int event = 0;

    queue->take(&event);
}
```

I'll have a `invalid old size` error on realloc.

So if I pass a null pointer or a heap allocated variable it'll work but if I pass a stack variable address it won't.

**Is there a way to allow stack variable address to be passed to `take()` function ?**

Comment: If something hurts, don't do it. Your design is beyond wrong.

Comment: `typedef struct element` -- There is no need for `typedef struct` in C++.  All you need is simply `struct element`.  Second, *I want the class to be as generic as possible* -- How is your class going to work if the element is a non-POD type, such as `std::string`?  Using `malloc`, `realloc`, etc. will not work.  This looks like an attempt using `C` constructs, with the expectation that `C` works the same way as C++ w.r.t. creating instances dynamically and handling these instances.  Being "generic" is achieved in C++ by usage of templates.

Comment: have fun with [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to allow stack variable address to be passed to take()
>   function ?

The short answer is no.  `malloc()`/`free()`/`realloc()` can only work with heap-allocated memory; they will not work with stack-allocated memory.

As for how you might work around this problem, I think it will require some redesign.  My first suggestion is to run as far away as possible from `(void *)` -- void-pointers are extremely unsafe and difficult to use correctly, because the compiler knows nothing about what they point to, and therefore cannot generate errors when the programmer does something incorrectly; this leads to lots of runtime problems.  They are more of a C-language construct, still supported in C++ to provide C compatibility, but C++ has better and safer ways to do the same things.

In particular, if all of the data-elements of your queue are expected to be the same type, then the obvious thing to do would be to make your Blocking_queue class templated with that type as a template-argument; then the user can specify e.g. `Blocking_queue<MyFavoriteDataType>` and use whatever type he likes, and provide easy-to-use by-value semantics (similar to those provided by e.g. `std::vector` and friends)

If you want to allow mixing data-elements of different types, then the best thing to do would be the above again, but define a common base-class for the objects, and then you can instantiate a `Blocking_queue<std::shared_ptr<TheCommonBaseClass> >` object that will accept shared-pointers to any heap-allocated object of any subclass of that base class.  (If you really need to pass shared-pointers to stack-allocated objects, you can do that by defining a custom allocator for the shared pointer, but note that doing so opens the door to object-lifetime-mismatch issues, since the stack objects may be destroyed before they are removed from the queue)